# How to avoid values overlapping in Qlikview?

Tags: charts, data-visualization, designer, qlikview

I am creating a Line chart and I have set **Values on data points** property to true, so It's showing values also. The problem is I am using two dimension so values are getting overlapped. This is what I am talking about :

[image]

Is there any solutiuon to this problem OR Is there any alternate to this prob ?

Comment: Unfortunately, short of changing the font size, chart Y-scale or chart object size, there isn't a way to prevent this. For whatever reason, Qlik has chosen to not give the developer the ability position individual data labels. As a workaround, I often include buttons to allow the user to toggle labels on/off for each expression.

Comment: you are right there is no way to change the setting directly, using button to toggle the labels is a good idea.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extend the size of your graph if it's possible, if not I don't think there's an other solution to your issue.

If I Were you, I would transform the line chart into a bar chart which is more lisible.